# Get 401 Error when try to Get Power BI Activity Events (Audit Logs)

Tags: azure, powerbi

I'm trying to get Power BI audit logs using service principal.

I follow every step in creating Azure principal Embed Power BI content in a https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal#add-a-service-principal-or-security-group-by-using-powershell

1.Create app

2.Create secret

3. Add app into group
4. Give all permitions to app

Tenant.Read.All, Tenant.ReadWrite.All;Report.ReadWrite.All, Report.Read.All, Dataset.Read.All;Auditlog.Read.All; Workspace.Read.All;Workspace.ReadWrite.All; and many other permitions.
[image]

5. Enable "Allow service principal to use Power BI API's" and "Enable content in apps" in Power BI admin portal.

I can get acces token and run few API calls like :

"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups" and
"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/reports"

But when try to get activity events

```
"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/activityevents?startDateTime='2023-02-13T07:55:00.000Z'&endDateTime='2023-02-13T08:55:00.000Z'&$filter=Activity" and 
"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/activityevents?startDateTime='" + activityDate + "T00:00:00'&endDateTime='" + activityDate + "T23:59:59'"
```

- **get 401 error**.

Or post this request "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetId}/refreshes" get 403 error.
My Python script is follow:

```
TENANT_ID = '1eb27ef3-976f-4600-a791-*******'
CLIENT_ID = 'd5376b05-a655-463b-ae9f-*******'
CLIENT_SECRET = '**************************'
SCOPE_BASE = ['https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default']
AUTHORITY_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations'
try:
    authority = AUTHORITY_URL.replace('organizations', TENANT_ID)
    clientapp = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(CLIENT_ID, client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET, authority=authority)
    response = clientapp.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=SCOPE_BASE)
    try:
        access_token = response['access_token']
        activityDate = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
        activityDate = activityDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

        url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/activityevents?startDateTime='" + activityDate + "T00:00:00'&endDateTime='" + activityDate + "T23:59:59'"
        header = {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization':f'Bearer {access_token}'}
        api_call = requests.get(url=url, headers=header)
        print(api_call)
        print(api_call.json())

    except KeyError:
        raise Exception(response['error_description'])

except Exception as ex:
    raise Exception('Error retrieving Access token\n' + str(ex))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/get-activity-events#permissions), it states:

> When running under service prinicipal authentication, an app **must not** have any admin-consent required premissions for Power BI set on it in the Azure portal.

and for the required scope:

> Must not be present when authentication via a service principal is used.

So remove the consent and delete all the privileges from the application and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much. I turn off permitions Tenant.ReadAll, Tenant.ReadWriteAll and now can get activity events. Struggled with this problem for 2 weeks.